# MEAN stack/angularjs post request failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, mean-stack

Im struggeling to get the server to accept my post request, cause i would like to post some data on /api/kill .

***For some reason it wont work. how can i make it work?***

I downloaded the latest release for Mean stack by this link: https://github.com/dickeyxxx/mean-sample

i tried to edit the article module to start with.

```
var promise = $http.put('/api/kill', null);
```

response:

```
angular.js:11756 PUT SITE:3000/server-error 404 (Not Found)
```

attempt number two:

```
var promise = $http.post('/api/kill', null);
```

returns:

```
angular.js:11756 POST SITE:3000/api/kill 404 (Not Found)
```

( only if the route is:

```
  app.route('/api/kill').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(articles.list)
    .put(articles.killuserbyid)
```

so, if route is :

```
app.route('/api/kill').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(articles.list)
.post(articles.killuserbyid)
```

it would return the orginal:

```
angular.js:11756 PUT SITE:3000/server-error 404 (Not Found)
```

***MY codes:***

in my article.server.routes.js i do have:

```
    'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies
 */
var articlesPolicy = require('../policies/articles.server.policy'),
  articles = require('../controllers/articles.server.controller');

module.exports = function (app) {
  // Articles collection routes

    app.route('/api/kill').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(articles.list)
    .put(articles.killuserbyid)
    .delete(articles.delete);

  // Single article routes





  // Finish by binding the article middleware
  app.param('articleId', articles.articleByID);
};
```

my `invokeRolesPolicies` in articles.server.policy:

```
    exports.invokeRolesPolicies = function () {
  acl.allow([{
    roles: ['admin'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/kill',
      permissions: '*'
    }]
  }, {
    roles: ['user'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/kill',
      permissions: '*'
    }]
  }, {
    roles: ['guest'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/kill',
      permissions: '*'
    }]
  }]);
};
```

my `ArticlesListController` function in list-articles.client.controller:

```
  ArticlesListController.$inject = ['ArticlesService','$scope'];

  function ArticlesListController(ArticlesService,$scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.testing = function() {



            ArticlesService.test();



    }




  }
```

and, finally my articleservice function (articles.client.service)

```
ArticlesService.$inject = ['$resource','$http'];

  function ArticlesService($resource,$http) {

        var o = [];

        o.test = function() {
            console.log("tester..");

            var promise = $http.put('/api/kill', null);


            promise.then(function(payload) {
                console.log(payload.data);

              });
        }


        return o;

  }
```

Comment: Looks like it's 404 issue

Comment: Of course @shammon but how do i fix IT?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question/issue correctly, you are receiving a 404 error, when issuing a POST request to `/api/kill` in `article.server.routes.js`

Correct me if I'm wrong, but your current route in your code is:

```
app.route('/api/kill').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(articles.list)
.put(articles.killuserbyid)
.delete(articles.delete);
```

As it stands, there are only route handlers for `GET` `PUT` and `DELETE` requests. There are no route handlers for `POST` requests, so your server is issuing a 404 error since it cannot find a route handler to respond to `POST` requests to `/api/kill`.

Try modifying your route to something like the below and see if you get a response

```
app.route('/api/kill').all(articlesPolicy.isAllowed)
.get(articles.list)
.post(...) // replace ... with appropriate route handling function
.put(articles.killuserbyid)
.delete(articles.delete);
```